# what is the most specific css reference for this

Tags: html, css

I am trying to override the css from another file and I would like to know how specific of a reference I would need to override it.

Here is the page I am working with if you'd like to take a look:

http://www.bolistylus.com/shop/

This is what I'm trying to override:

```
.products li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Here is the HTML I'm working with:

```
<div id="main">

<section id="primary"><div id="content" role="main"><div id="breadcrumb"><a class="home" href="http://www.bolistylus.com">Home</a>  &rsaquo; <a href="http://www.bolistylus.com/shop/">Shop</a></div>
            <h1 class="page-title">All Products</h1>

<ul class="products">   
     <li class="product first">
        <a href="http://www.bolistylus.com/shop/boli-2/">

            <img width="150" height="150" src="http://www.bolistylus.com/wp-content/uploads/pinkproduct-150x150.png" class="attachment-shop_small wp-post-image" alt="pinkproduct" title="pinkproduct" />

            <strong>Boli Pink</strong>

            <span class="price">&#36;24.00</span>
        </a>

        <a href="/shop/?add-to-cart=38&_n=188fa640fb" class="button">Add to cart</a>
    </li>   <li class="product ">
    </li></ul><div class="clear"></div> 

</div></section>

    </div><!-- #main -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.products li` has a specificity of `(0, 0, 1, 1)`

a minimal higher specificity can be created with

`ul.products li` which has a specificity of `(0, 0, 1, 2)`

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DAL9A/

Comment: How do you determine specificity? ([`.products li.product`](http://jsfiddle.net/PHaSs/) also works.)

Comment: Here is a nice succinct article http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/ and here's the actual W3 recommendation for CSS2.1 http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more specific. What does the `{0, 0, 1, 1}` refer to?

Comment: @Jared - check out the second link that twaddington provided. the examples show the four comma separated values clearly. Maybe I shouldn't have put them inside braces. I'll take them out.

Comment: I just think some context within the answer to explain what you were calculating was perhaps not necessary, but very much value-added. `:)`

Comment: `0 0 1 1` is not an inline style, no id attributes, one other attribute, one element name.

Answer (score 0):

.products li and you can use !important if it doesnt take. Try to load that after what your trying to override.

**UPDATE***
Try just using ".product"

Actually just ready your comments. What are you trying to target? The image? If So you should get the width and height out of inline and apply it in CSS

Comment: How can I change the order that the stylesheets load? Thanks

Comment: Here's what I did and it still didn't override: ``.products li {
    width: 270px !important;
}``